# How to get check box checked or not when click submit button razor page mvc?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I working on asp.net core MVC razor page . I face issue I can't get checkbox checked or not
on page model razor page .

so which checkbox have checked or not checked this is exactly I need to get on page model MVC.

so if checkboxes StockTake and ShelfLabelPrint  checked so I will get value 1 and 2 is true on page model .

checkbox Transfer not checked so it will get value 3 status false .

```
public class AddUserAccessModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public UC.ADC.Core.Entities.SQL.UserAccess UserAccess { get; set; }
public async Task OnPost(UC.ADC.Core.Entities.SQL.UserAccess useraccess)
        {
       string[] checkedModuleCodes = Request.Form["checks"];
      // How to recognize which check box have checked or not here
        }
    }
```

ON AddUserAccess.cshtml Razor view

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <form method="post">
        <button  type="submit" class="col-sm-1 btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        
        <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="user-id" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label" style="font-size:15px;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight: bold;">User ID</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input id="useraccess-id"  asp-for="UserAccess.UserId" type="text" class="form-control" style=" margin-left:10px;font-size:15px;font-family: 'Open Sans' , sans-serif;font-weight: bold;" />
            </div>
        </div>
    <input id="StockTake" name="checks" type="checkbox" asp-for="UserAccess.MODULECODE" value="1">
        <label for="lblStockTake">Stock Take</label>
    <input id="ShelfLabelPrint" name="checks" type="checkbox" asp-for="UserAccess.MODULECODE" value="2">
        <label for="lblShelfLabel">Shelf Label Print</label>

    <input id="Transfer" name="checks" type="checkbox" asp-for="UserAccess.MODULECODE" value="3">
        <label for="lblTransfer" style="margin-right:5px;">Transfer</label>

        
       
        
    </form>
```

expectation result I need as below

[image: How to detect check box check or not multi checkbox]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, You can create a model contains the `value` and `isChekced` state, Please refer to this demo.

**Model**

```
public class Result
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public bool isChecked { get; set; }
         public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

**Add this model into page model**

```
[BindProperty]
public List<Result> result { get; set; } = new List<Result>();
```

**Use javascript to set the value of result according to if user check the checkbox in the view**

```
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
<form method="post">
    <button type="submit" class="col-sm-1 btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="user-id" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label" style="font-size:15px;font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;font-weight: bold;">User ID</label>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input id="useraccess-id" asp-for="UserAccess.UserId" type="text" class="form-control" style=" margin-left:10px;font-size:15px;font-family: 'Open Sans' , sans-serif;font-weight: bold;" />
        </div>
    </div>

<div>
    <input id="StockTake" name="checks" type="checkbox" asp-for="UserAccess.MODULECODE" value="1">
    
    <input name="result[0].isChecked" type="hidden" value="false"/>
    <input name="result[0].value" type="hidden" value="1"/>
    <input name="result[0].name" type="hidden" value="StockTake" />
    <label for="lblStockTake">Stock Take</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input id="ShelfLabelPrint" name="checks" type="checkbox" asp-for="UserAccess.MODULECODE" value="2">
    <input name="result[1].isChecked" type="hidden" value="false" />
    <input name="result[1].value" type="hidden" value="2" />
    <input name="result[1].name" type="hidden" value="ShelfLabelPrint" />
    <label for="lblShelfLabel">Shelf Label Print</label>
</div>

<div>
    <input id="Transfer" name="checks" type="checkbox" asp-for="UserAccess.MODULECODE" value="3">
    <input name="result[2].isChecked" type="hidden" value="false" />
    <input name="result[2].value" type="hidden" value="3" />
    <input name="result[2].name" type="hidden" value="Transfer" />
    <label for="lblTransfer" style="margin-right:5px;">Transfer</label>
</div>    
</form>


@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#StockTake').change(function () {
                var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
                $('input[name="result[0].isChecked"]').val(isChecked);
            });

            $('#ShelfLabelPrint').change(function () {
                var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
                $('input[name="result[1].isChecked').val(isChecked);
            });

            $('#Transfer').change(function () {
                var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');
                $('input[name="result[2].isChecked').val(isChecked);
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Gif demo

[image]